# How to execute multiple commands in command prompt using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am writing a batch file to execute the command (to execute Bitvise SFTP)

```
start cmd /k sftpc [SERVERNAME] -pk=1
```

After which the command prompt ask the following

```
Accept and (S)ave/(A)ccept for This Session/(C)ancel (S/A/C)?
```

Now the batch file should execute the next command as "A" to go through process.

I want automate the process of providing input "A" in command prompt. How can a batch file execute commands continuously ?

**Updated :**

After accepting the session, there are two more commands that needs to be executed,

```
cd [RemoteLocation]


get *.*
```

How to automate these two commands after the first two commands using the same batch file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this to send an "`A`" to `sftpc`:

```
start cmd /k "echo A | sftpc [SERVERNAME] -pk=1"
```

I don't have `sftpc` and am just trying a suggestion to help out...

**Updated:**

If you have multiple commands to give to `sftpc`, you may find that one of the following methods works, depending on how `sftpc` works - I am working blind here - still don't have, or want, sftpc.

```
start cmd /k "echo A & echo cd somewhere & echo get *.* | sftpc [SERVERNAME] -pk=1"
```

... change "somewhere" to wherever you want to go to.

Or maybe:

Save the following in a file called `ftp.cmd`

```
A
cd somewhere
get *.*
```

Then try:

```
start cmd /k "sftpc [SERVERNAME] -pk=1 < ftp.cmd"
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, could you consider accpeting it as the answer (by clicking the hollow check mark near the voting scores) so I get a lovely big green tick please? If not, please say what didn't work and I'll try and assist you further. Thank you.

Comment: It worked, but i could not follow the same way for other commands which has to be executed. I have accepted this as answer, as it justifies my question, But there are some other commands to be executed after "echo A" which is not working the same way. After the confirmation is given with "echo A" I need to execute "cd [Location]". How to do it ?

Comment: How many more commands are there? Can you click "Edit" under your question and update it with the rest if the commands you want to execute and write "UPDATED" in bold across your question so people take another look.

Comment: I have updated my answer - let me, and the world, know how it goes please.

Comment: Get *.* is executed, but i could see "Session terminated on user's request." During the manual process, Get *.* works. I think the session is ended and do we need to put some pause or wait time for the cmd to run and execute the get command ???

Comment: I was able to download the files now. But i have used "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul" after "get" So, is this a correct approach ?

Comment: I am not sure `get *.*` is the correct syntax. If it is a Unix server, it would be `get *` rather than `get *.*`. Also, you may need to put `quit` or `bye` at the end. You could also try adding `dir` or `ls` at the end to see if that gets executed after your `get`.